Multiple security parameters to the same schema definition not visible on ui
I am using Multiple security parameters to the same schema definition, but when i click on this Authorise button it shows me both parameter
Authorise button is mentioned to display modal
But when i click on this Lock icon it shows me only one parameter in modal
Lock Icon is mentioned to display modal
I want to show both param on Lock icon too
my code id
openapi: 3.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://api.test.com/api/v2
    description: Default server
info:
  description: |
    test
  version: 2.0.0
  title: API V2
  termsOfService: "http://swagger.io/terms/"
  contact:
    name: API Support
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
tags:
  - name: DNS MADE EASY
    description: "All the endpoints related to DNS MADE EASY Addon"
    x-displayName: DNS MADE EASY
paths:
  /dme/domains:
    parameters:
      - name: X-Device-Id
        in: header
        description: "(should be same as login route)"
        required: true
        schema:
          type: number
    get:
      tags:
        - DNS MADE EASY
      summary: Fetch all domains
      description: "Returns a list of domains created by this user"
      operationId: getDomains
      responses:
        "400":
          description: Invalid ID supplied
        "404":
          description: Domain not found
        "405":
          description: Validation exception
      security:
         - ApiKeyAuth: []
components:
  schemas:
    ApiResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        type:
          type: string
        message:
          type: string
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: Access-Token
    deviceId:
      type: apiKey
      name: Device-Id
      in: header


I want to show both param on Lock icon too
i have tried this solution too but not working for me
Using an API Key & Secret for Swagger Security Scheme
Swagger - Adding multiple security parameters to the same schema definition
